# Multilistmap - getting data from resultset

Tags: java, resultset

I am using LinkedListMultimap to store values from my resultset .

```
//Map declaration: 
ListMultimap<String, String> multimap = LinkedListMultimap.create();
while(rs.next())
{
multimap.put(address,Name);
}
```

Database Values :

Add1     Phalani
  Add1     Vaishu

When the resultset stores my data ,for the same key both the values are stored.
Output of Multi Map : {Add1=[Vaishu ,Phalani]}

But the output I expect : {Add1=[Phalani,Vaishu]}
Same as it is stored in the database .What can be done.

Comment: I think you need to elaborate a bit more. Can you should use the complete code? What database are you talking about?

Comment: am using SQL ..The map is storing the values with same key in Alphabetical order. Eg : If same key the values are stored in alphabetiocal order . {Add1=[Afrin ,Bala, Phalani]}   . But I want the values to be store in same order as comes in resultset,If in resultset the order is {Bala ,Phalani,Afrin},In the map too I should get the same order.